# How to bootstrap Angular inside a shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, shadow

I'm looking for guidance on how to bootstrap an angular module inside of a shadow DOM. Currently our app is failing because the root component selector is searching at the document level, and it can't see the matching element inside the shadow DOM.

Is there a way to pass in the root element of the shadow DOM and have Angular scope it's search for matching component selectors within that element?

For example, we have another application built in Vue that has the exact same scenario, and we're able to do it as simply as this:

```
new Vue({ el: referenceToMyRootElementInsideTheShadowDom })
```

I have to think Angular must support this kind of scenario, but I can't find any examples. Fwiw, I'm specifically working with Angular 11 in this case.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: Sort of, I did eventually figure out the recipe to make this load, but I didn't move forward with the solution because Angular automatically adds style tags in the <head> tag at runtime, which was outside the shadow dom so broke the styling. Pretty disappointing. Ended up going another route and not using shadow dom the way I originally intended. I'd share the code I came up with to make angular run, but unfortunately I never saved it and don't recall what was involved.

Comment: Well I found e solution, you need to change the encapsulation to `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`, the you can import all the styles to the component style file, and angular would add it as child of the shadow root